# vline webrtc: memorize allow access camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc, vline

I'm using a [vline](https://vline.com/) service in my webpage.

There is a way to memorize the access to webcam?

Every time what i call a `MediaSession.stop()` i need to say "allow" to the browser for give the access to the resource.

My objective is make a page where there are a multiple conversations in sequence. How i can close the actual conversation and open a new with another remote person without that?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: you can change the browser settings, but it gives user kinda security so no script can use the camera  until the user accepts that.

Answer (score 0):

microphone and webcam permissions are not part of vline - those are a security feature built into the browser - only the end user may decide on a per site basis whether their choice is remembered - the only thing i could suggest is that you somehow keep the stream rolling for the entire duration (do not call .stop()) but simply hide/mute the output whenever youd prefer it to be off - but user will still need to "allow" this at least once (or once per session if they have not opted to remember the permissions)

Comment: thank for reply. I have already thinked to mute audio and hide a video but i can't negate, in this way, that the user unhide (easy access through css) a video and see the other person in remote cam.

Comment: So i have decided to load all person with loadPerson(id) and prevent close session by vline ( when all remote media session are closed, vline, close automatically the session seem.. )

Answer (score 0):

If you serve your page from https instead of http, the browser will remember your settings.